# SignalR - very beginner

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have just started learning what signalR is. I tried the dragging the box example. In my application I would like to create a 'facebook like notification mechanism'. When a '1' pops up somewhere, it pops up on all the clients. But I don't know where I should start. At the moment the notification mechanism connects to the database and notifications pop up when refreshing (and only on 1 client). Can anyone please guide me :)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure we can! :)
Have you read the wiki on project's page? There is all necessary information there.
http://www.asp.net/signalr

For example you can start from here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: completed my aim a few days ago :D